# Devexpress MessageBox is closing automatically

Tags: devexpress, progress-bar, messagebox

I have a Devexpress form which is having Progress bar and MessageBox.
When i click search button on my form,the progress bar displays percentage and then grid will be bind with records.
and when it returns no records, message box will appear after progress bar like "No Records Found"

but after showing No records found,it is closing automatically with out clicking OK or CANCEL button on messagebox

Code for Progress Bar

```
namespace DMS
{
public partial class ProgressBar : WaitForm
{
    public ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Overrides
    public override void SetCaption(string caption)
    {
        base.SetCaption(caption);
        this.progressPanel1.Caption = caption;
    }
    public override void SetDescription(string description)
    {
        base.SetDescription(description);
        this.progressPanel1.Description = description;
    }
    public override void ProcessCommand(Enum cmd, object arg)
    {
        base.ProcessCommand(cmd, arg);
    }
    #endregion

    private void progressBarControl1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = int.Parse(Math.Floor(double.Parse(this.progressBarControl1.EditValue.ToString())).ToString());                
            if (i.ToString().EndsWith("0"))
            {
                //satya
                //i += 5;
                i += 0;
            }
            this.Opacity = 100;
            SetCaption("Please Wait...");
            SetDescription(i.ToString() + "% Completed...");
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString() + " " + ex.Source.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Code for Showing Message Box

```
private void btnshow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dtstartdate.DateTime.Date > dtEnddate.DateTime.Date)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show("Start date should be less than End date", Program.MessageBoxTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                dtstartdate.Focus();
                return;
            }
            string CommandText = "select * from DMS_View_Payments where v_Paymentdate between '" + General.DateToDatabase(this.dtstartdate.DateTime.ToShortDateString())
                + "' and '" + General.DateToDatabase(this.dtEnddate.DateTime.ToShortDateString()) + "'";
            if (ccbeForClient.EditValue.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                CommandText += " and v_clientid in (" + this.ccbeForClient.EditValue.ToString() + ")";
            }
            else if (Logs.UserLimitedClients != "0")
            {
                CommandText += " and v_clientid in (" + Logs.UserLimitedClients + ")";
            }
            if (ccbeForBatch.Text.Trim() != "" && ccbeForBatch.Text.Trim() != "--")
            {
                string selected_client_list = "";
                if (ccbeForBatch.Text.Trim() != "" && ccbeForBatch.Text.Trim() != "--")
                {
                    //selected_client_list = ccbe_client_list.Text.Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", "','");
                    string source = ccbeForBatch.Text;
                    string[] split = source.Split(',');
                    string changed = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                    {
                        changed += "," + split[i].Trim();
                    }
                    //string output = changed.Trim(',').Replace(",", "','");
                    selected_client_list = changed.Trim(',').Replace(",", "','");
                }
                else
                {
                    selected_client_list = "";
                }
                CommandText += " and v_Batch in ('" + selected_client_list + "') ";
            }
            if (ccbeForBranch.EditValue.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                CommandText += " and v_BRANCH_ID in (" + ccbeForBranch.EditValue.ToString() + ")";
            }
            if (ccbeForCollector.EditValue.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                CommandText += " and V_CollectorId in (" + ccbeForCollector.EditValue.ToString() + ")";
            }
            else if (DevXCharts.EmpIdsForHierarchey != "")
            {
                CommandText += " and V_CollectorId in (" + DevXCharts.EmpIdsForHierarchey.ToString() + ")";
            }
            if (ccbeForAccountType.Text.Trim() != "" && ccbeForAccountType.Text.Trim() != "--")
            {
                string selected_client_list = "";
                if (ccbeForAccountType.Text.Trim() != "" && ccbeForAccountType.Text.Trim() != "--")
                {
                    //selected_client_list = ccbe_client_list.Text.Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", "','");
                    string source = ccbeForAccountType.Text;
                    string[] split = source.Split(',');
                    string changed = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                    {
                        changed += "," + split[i].Trim();
                    }
                    //string output = changed.Trim(',').Replace(",", "','");
                    selected_client_list = changed.Trim(',').Replace(",", "','");
                }
                else
                {
                    selected_client_list = "";
                }
                CommandText += " and v_AccountType in ('" + selected_client_list + "') ";
            }
            if (radioPayment.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                CommandText += " and v_Confirmed='Y'";
            }
            else if (radioPayment.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                CommandText += " and v_Confirmed='N'";
            }
            if (radioCases.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                CommandText += " and v_flagabort='0'";
            }
            else if (radioCases.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                CommandText += " and v_flagabort='1'";
            }
            CommandText += " order by v_debtorname";
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (objPB != null)
            {
                objPB.Close();
                objPB = null;
            }
            objPB = new ProgressBar();
            objPB.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            objPB.progressBarControl1.EditValue = 20;
            objPB.TopMost = true;
            objPB.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            Application.DoEvents();
            objPB.Show();
            Application.DoEvents();
            SqlDataAdapter sql_for_debtors = new SqlDataAdapter(CommandText, DBConString.ConnectionString());
            DataSet ds_for_rhb = new DataSet();
            sql_for_debtors.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            sql_for_debtors.Fill(ds_for_rhb, "DMS_View_Payments");
            sql_for_debtors.Dispose();
            Application.DoEvents();
            objPB.progressBarControl1.EditValue = 40;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (ds_for_rhb.Tables["DMS_View_Payments"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                XrtPaymentsDevx obj_report = new XrtPaymentsDevx();
                obj_report.xrlReportHeader.Text = "Payments From " + this.dtstartdate.DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " To " + this.dtEnddate.DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                string SelectionCriteria = "";
                if (this.ccbeForClient.Text != "" && this.ccbeForClient.Text != "--")
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Client: " + this.ccbeForClient.Text + " , ";
                }
                if (this.ccbeForBatch.Text != "" && this.ccbeForBatch.Text != "--")
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Batch: " + this.ccbeForBatch.Text + " , ";
                }
                if (this.ccbeForBranch.Text != "" && this.ccbeForBranch.Text != "--")
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Branch: " + this.ccbeForBranch.Text + " , ";
                }
                if (this.ccbeForCollector.Text != "" && this.ccbeForCollector.Text != "--")
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Collector: " + this.ccbeForCollector.Text + " , ";
                }
                if (this.ccbeForAccountType.Text != "" && this.ccbeForAccountType.Text != "--")
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " AccType: " + this.ccbeForAccountType.Text + " , ";
                }
                if (radioPayment.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Payment Confirmed='Y'" + " , ";
                }
                else if (radioPayment.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Payment Confirmed='N'" + " , ";
                }
                else if (radioPayment.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Payment Confirmed='Y' And 'N'" + " , ";
                }
                if (radioCases.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Abort Cases" + " , ";
                }
                else if (radioCases.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Active Cases" + " , ";
                }
                else if (radioCases.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    SelectionCriteria += " Both Active And Abort Cases" + " , ";
                }
                obj_report.xrlSelectionCriteria.Text = SelectionCriteria;
                obj_report.DataSource = ds_for_rhb;
                obj_report.DataMember = "DMS_View_Payments";
                Application.DoEvents();
                objPB.progressBarControl1.EditValue = 60;
                Application.DoEvents();
                obj_report.CreateDataBindings();
                Application.DoEvents();
                objPB.progressBarControl1.EditValue = 80;
                Application.DoEvents();
                //obj_report.bind_data();
                obj_report.ShowPreview();
                Application.DoEvents();
                objPB.progressBarControl1.EditValue = 90;
                Application.DoEvents();
                Application.DoEvents();
                objPB.progressBarControl1.EditValue = 100;
                Application.DoEvents();
                objPB.Close();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            else
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show("No Records(s) Found", Program.MessageBoxTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                objPB.progressBarControl1.EditValue = 100;                    
                //objPB.progressBarControl1.EditValue = 100;
                Application.DoEvents();
                objPB.Close();

                //Application.DoEvents();




                //objPB.progressBarControl1.EditValue = 100;                    
                //Application.DoEvents();
                //objPB.Close();                    
                //XtraMessageBox.Show("No Records(s) Found", Program.MessageBoxTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString() + " " + ex.Source.ToString(), Program.MessageBoxTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked for any exception in your program?? provide code where you suspect the error...

Comment: It is difficult to determine the cause of this issue due to a lack of information. Please provide the exact code...

Comment: your `Code for Showing Message Box` is looking faulty.. debug that code with break point when there are no record in search result

Comment: one more detail - as far as I can see you are using the SplashScreenManager and it's WaitForm. If so please also add a code for this WaitForm usage (showing/closing). Since the WaitForm is working in separate thread the reason of unexpected MessageBox closing depends on WaitForm form closing

Comment: can you give me a sample code for closing of waitform?
or atleast provide some link for it?

Comment: @user1929704: [How to: Dynamically Update Wait Form's Caption or Description](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10832)

Comment: @user1929704: [WaitForm](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10824)

Comment: @DmitryG : I didn't get solution,where do i need to put the showing and closing code.Actually i am new to devexpress controls.plz help me

Comment: @user1929704: I wanna help you, but I can't, because i have no code for your WaitFrom usage. Please post the code for search button click and etc. (how do you starting search? how do you updating search progress, how do you process search result? where and how do you using the first code fragment?)

Comment: If objPB is your main form, the application is exit when you close it. Just put this line after the line where you show the message box.

Comment: @Uranus : but the progress bar is showing on the background.i want to close the progress bar first and then the message box should appear

Comment: @DmitryG : Please see the code and give me a solution

Comment: @user1929704: I have updated this thread with answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **reason of the issue is incorrect usage of WaitForm** instance.
You should'not show/hide the WaitForm directly rather then use the [SplashScreenManager API](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10824) to show/hide and interact with WaitForm.
Here i'll try to get you correct approach:

At first, the code for running search operation with WaitForm showing should looks like this:

```
void OnRunSearchOperation_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    bool success = false;
    SplashScreenManager.ShowForm(this, typeof(ProgressWaitForm), false, false); 
    try {
        // here you can run some long time operations
        success = SearchOperation();
    }
    finally { SplashScreenManager.CloseForm(); }
    if(!success) {
        XtraMessageBox.Show(this, "No entries found");
    }
}
bool SearchOperation() {
    // THIS IS SEARCH OPERATION IMITATION 
    const int count = 70000000;
    int stepThreshold = count / 100;
    decimal dec = 1.41M;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        dec /= 2;
        if((i % stepThreshold) == 0) 
            SplashScreenManager.Default.SendCommand(WaitFormCommand.PerformStep, null);
    }
    return false; // result
}
```

Here are the `WaitFormCommand` and 'ProgressWaitForm' implementation:

```
public enum WaitFormCommand {
    PerformStep
}
public partial class ProgressWaitForm : WaitForm {
    public ProgressWaitForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #region Overrides
    public override void ProcessCommand(Enum cmd, object arg) {
        base.ProcessCommand(cmd, arg);
        WaitFormCommand wfCmd = (WaitFormCommand)cmd;
        if(wfCmd == WaitFormCommand.PerformStep) 
            progressBarControl1.PerformStep();
    }
    #endregion
}
```